# SQL server 2008 - how to get column name and value together?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, json

I'm not sure if it's possible..

I'm using SQL server 2008 and Java.

I have a table

```
--------------
|   users    |
--------------
|  name      |
|  address   |
|  password  |
|____________|
```

Then I do:

```
SELECT name, address, password FROM users;
```

I got all values from each column.

But what if **I ALSO want to get column names too.**

When query result is returned, I want to know which column is being queried.

How do I get **value and columns together?** Is it possible without changing the query using Java?

**code**

```
em = EmProvider.getInstance().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT name, address, password, birthday FROM users");
//query result is stored in list consists of object array
List<Object[]> out = query.getResultList();

//so result is like this
List<
   [john, 1st ave, 1234, 12/12/2010]
   [mike, 2st ave, 1111, 12/11/2011]
>

//now I create JSON
{name:john, address:1st ave, birthday....}
```

But the query could change so when I construct JSON I don't want to hard-code "name" or "address".

Comment: Not understanding your question. can you show sample output on how you want to display column names?

Comment: You already know what columns and values go together. Your result set has the columns labeled, and you also know what columns you asked for. Your question would probably make more sense if you shared the code you're using where it's not clear or the specific problem you're having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column names come from the ResultSetMetaData.

For example:

```
String sql = "Select * from Activity";
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
int columns = md.getColumnCount();

//  Get column names

for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
{
    columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );
}

//  Get row data

while (rs.next())
{
    Vector row = new Vector(columns);

    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
    }

    data.addElement( row );
}
```

Comment: This is the way to do it assuming you're using JDBC. But I think OP is using JPA.

Comment: @Ray, maybe but if you look at the original posting of the question (before it was revised) you will see that no code was posted so I gave the suggestion based on the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this - Assuming you need columnname followed by columnvalue -

```
SELECT "name" as column1, name, "address" as column2, address, "password" as column3, password FROM users;
```